# NodeJs, es6 debugging issue in VSC

Tags: ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code, babeljs

I am trying to debug nodeJS code in Visual Studio Code but unfortunately I get info that:

`(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { start } from './server'`

As far as I know it means that es6 features are not supported, but I think that my *package.json* and *.babelrc* are correct.
**.babelrc:**

```
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    ["@babel/env", {
      "targets": {
        "node": "current"
      }
    }]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"
  ],
  "sourceMaps": true,
  "retainLines": true
}
```

**package.json:**

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.1",
    "babel-jest": "^23.4.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "eslint": "^4.15.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^2.9.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^11.0.0",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^21.15.1",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^7.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.1.0",
    "jest": "^23.6.0",
    "mock-req-res": "^1.0.2",
    "mongodb-memory-server": "^5.2.8",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.3",
    "prettier": "^1.15.2",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "supertest": "^3.3.0"
  },
```

Any ideas what is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try

```
"presets": [
   [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "current"
        }
      }
   ]
],
```

It will automatically compile your code as required for node

Comment: Unfortunately this not resolved my issue. Same error still exists.

Comment: Can you please share the code gist? I will be able to run and debug it.